# Jetpack compose animation to expand a view to fullscreen with offset

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Say we have 4 boxes which is inside row or column.when clicked on each I have to resize the box or expand the box to fullscreen. The main thing is if the current box size is 100 by 100 and it is in 10 dp padding from top then the expansion should start exactly from the same corners and collapse animation should collapse to same corners.

But now if we expand the width and height to fullwidth(calculated) or full height( calculated screen size), it will push and squeeze the other item, which should not happen.

2nd approach I did is created a box separately and move the box to the clicked box position using offset and expand then newly created box to have the animation of expand and collapse. But problem here is it won’t use or override the offset to fullwidth and height, it will expand within the offset.

Any solution to do?
Either expand the clicked box to full size( it should be inside row or box) without moving the other views, just a overlay kind of expansion.
Or expand a box which will be in the parent view which we have to expand and collapse from the clicked position view.

Example:

[image: sample screen]